# Vue SPA + laravel Passport: how to authenticate properly?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, vue.js, laravel-passport

I'm trying to figure out what's the correct way to authenticate users with Passport for a Vue SPA. I can't figure out which grant type I should use considering that implicit grant is not recommended by IETF’s OAuth working group and the other methods require to pass the client_secret with the request, I'm a bit lost...

I was thinking password grant but I receive a refresh token and it’s not really secure to store it in the localstorage.

I also thought about the cookie injected by laravel passport in every request but I can’t find out how to login from my SPA with this approach...

Any lead on what’s the best / more secure way to do this ?

Thanks!